# Is there a `AcceptsOneWidget` which also `ProvidesResze` (other than `ScrollPanel`)?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I have a composite which extends `ResizeComposite` and has a `DockLayoutPanel` as its root.  I can stick it directly into `RootLayoutPanel` and it works because `DockLayoutPanel` `ProvidesResize`.

However, I'm wanting to use the MVP facilities in GWT 2.2, and `RootLayoutPanel` can't be passed to `ActivityManager#setDiplay(AcceptsOneWidget)` (since it's a multi-widget container).

At first glance, `ScrollPanel` appears to meet the dual requirement of implementing `AcceptsOneWidget` and both `ProvidesResize` and `RequiresResize`.

But I am finding that when I put my widget into a `ScrollPanel`, that it has a 'zero size', and I have to size it manually in order to see it, and I'm having trouble knowing what size to give it.  I'd rather a Panel that didn't necessarily scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ProvidesResize` to any widget by implementing it yourself, which is relatively simple - you just pass along all of the resize notifications you get to every sub-child that `RequiresResize`.

Alternatively, if you just want your panel to take up all of the available space, you might try setting the width and height on the `ScrollPanel` to `"100%"`.

Finally, here's my implementation of a LayoutPanel that `AcceptsOneWidget`:

```
public class PanelForView extends LayoutPanel implements AcceptsOneWidget
{
    IsWidget myWidget = null;

    @Override
    public void setWidget(IsWidget w)
    {
        if (myWidget != w)
        {
            if (myWidget != null)
            {
                remove(myWidget);
            }

            if (w != null)
            {
                add(w);
            }

            myWidget = w;
        }
    }

}
```

I've been using this in my commercial app for months without any problems, and it's easy to swap views in and out of it.  Feel free to use this code yourself.

Comment: Your `PanelForView` is exactly what I was looking for! I did not have luck with a `ScrollPanel` - I suspect it has an odd interaction with `DockLayoutPanel` (I will read/experiment further and maybe post another question).  My compiler found the @Overrides unnecessary :-)  Thanks.

Comment: Great!  Just be careful, because the default behaviors of `LayoutPanel` are still active.  If another part of your code gets ahold of one of these panels, it could still add multiple widgets, size them in different places, etc.  Making a really consistent `PanelForView` seemed like too much work for my needs ;)

Answer (score 3):

There will be a [SimpleLayoutPanel](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimpleLayoutPanel.java) in GWT 2.3, described as:

> `A simple panel that {@link ProvidesResize} to its one child.`